# Is $\mathbb{Z}[2x, 2x^2 , 2x^3 , \cdots ]$ noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I am currently studying for my University's preliminary exam in Algebra. I have come across a problem that is practice. I hope I can get some feedback on my proof.

Question:

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the polynomial ring in one variable over $\mathbb{Z}$. Define $T \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$ by $T = \mathbb{Z}[2x, 2x^2 , 2x^3 , \cdots ]$. Determine  whether  or  not $T$ is noetherian.

Proof:
Consider $$\pi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{2\mathbb{Z}[x]} \cong \mathbb{F}_2[x].$$
Note that $\pi(T) \subset \mathbb{F}_2$. Suppose that, for some $n \geq 1$: $$2x^{n + 1} = t_1 2x + t_2 2x^2 + \cdots + t_n 2x^n \quad \text{ for } t_i \in T.$$
Then in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ we have that $x^{n + 1} = t_1 x + t_2 x^2 + \cdots + t_n x^n$. By applying $\pi$ we get that $x^{n + 1} = c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \cdots + c_n x^n$ for $c_i \in \mathbb{F}_2$. This however is a contradiction, since the monomials $x^i$ are linearly independent over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$.  Therefore, the ascending chain of ideals in $T$ defined by $$(2x) \subset (2x,2x^2) \subset (2x,2x^2,2x^3) \subset \cdots $$
does not stabilize and thus $T$ is not noetherian.

Am I on the right track? If I am not, can I please have some hint's in the correct direction or let me know where in my proof I have failed.

Comment: Yes, it seems correct.

Comment: The proof looks correct to me. My only suggestion is stylistic: it'd be a bit easier to follow if you started the proof by giving the ascending chain of ideals, and then said that you're going to prove it doesn't stabilize, thus motivating the formulas. As written, you start by pulling an equation out of a hat, and it's only apparent why it's relevant once you've read further in the proof.